# URL Parameter reject by (probably) mod_security

Tags: php, apache, mod-security

i bought an app, but at the moment i see error 406 because the queries parameter include strange character:

index.php?Page=Addons&Addon=dynamiccontenttags&ajax=1&Action=ShowDynamicContentTag&EditorName=myDevEditControl&ContentArea=html&PageName=%%PAGE%%

if you see on the last param is &PageName=%%PAGE%%

i browse, and found out that mod_security is that one that forbid it. As i'm not too technie in apache, i found myself difficult to communicate this problem with my hosting support.

I want to know:

1. If i request to disable mod_security, do i put my site on risk ?
2. For simpler solution, Is there any rules that i can add in .htaccess so mod_security bypass value %%PAGE%% ?
3. For complex solution, If i want to ask my hosting support, what mod_security rules should i give to them ?

Thanks All!